# Challenges with SAML Front Channel Logout and clearing cookies in sites on different domains

Tags: saml-2.0, idp, third-party-cookies

I have sites on different domains: site1.domain1.com and site2.domain2.com. I've integrated these sites with an Identity Provider (IDP) using SAML, enabling Single Sign On (SSO) and Single Log out (SLO) mechanisms. The IDP is also on a different domain (idp.domain3.com). Sites are using a cookie to indicate if a user is logged in.

When a user logs out from one of the sites, the IDP initiates a Front Channel Logout. It displays a page with a hidden iframe containing a SAML Logout request for the second site. My goal on the second site is to clear the cookie from the site, that indicates the user is logged out. To do this, I set the cookie to expire in response to the SAML Logout request. I'm setting a cookie in that way: `Set-Cookie: cookieToRemove=expired; Path=/; Max-Age=0; SameSite=None; Secure`.

However, I encounter a problem when trying to clear the cookie. While Chrome and Edge successfully clear the cookie, Firefox does not. After some research, I discovered that the cookie is treated as a third-party cookie because the IDP is on a different domain than the site. Firefox blocks the setting of third-party cookies by default, and other browsers are expected to follow suit in the future.

I would like to know the recommended approach for handling SAML Front Channel Logout in the context of sites that use cookies, especially considering browsers that block third-party cookies.

Comment: Front channel single logout can always suffer from third-party cookie blocking if carried out in iframes, see [this remark](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-frontchannel-1_0.html#ThirdPartyContent) in the OpenID Connect specification. But SAML also knows a [logout flow](https://www.identityserver.com/articles/the-challenge-of-building-saml-single-logout) based on redirections rather than iframes.

Comment: Does this mean there is no way to clear cross-site cookies using front channel single logout now when browsers are starting to block or isolate them? On the IDP I'm testing, I see that both POST and HTTP Redirect bindings are used in an iframe, which indicates that front channel logout is being used

Comment: With 3rd-party cookie blocking, only [partitioned](https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/3pcd/chips) cookies are allowed in cross-site iframes.

Comment: I have checked the partitioned cookies and I'm unable to modify the site cookies that received the logout request from the IDP in an iframe created by the IDP. The cookies have different partition keys. The cookie that I set in the iframe gets the IDP domain partition key, as it's the top site for that frame, which is different from the site that needs to perform the logout.